# AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver - still unclear how to use it

Tags: kotlin, internationalization, spring-restcontroller

I tried to use the `AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver` in my application. I have made a lot of searches, but I still don't understand how to use it correctly. For the moment, the following code is the one that's working:

HeaderLocaleResolver class:

```
@Component
class HeaderLocaleResolver {

    private val acceptHeaderResolver = AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver()

    init {
        acceptHeaderResolver.defaultLocale = Locale.ENGLISH
    }

    fun getLocale(request: HttpServletRequest): Locale{
        return acceptHeaderResolver.resolveLocale(request)
    }
}
```

My rest controller class:

```
@RequestMapping("/rest/report")
@RestController
class PrinterController(private val printerService: PrinterService,
                        private val localeResolver: HeaderLocaleResolver) {

    @PostMapping("/{folder}/{templateName}")
    fun printReport(request: HttpServletRequest,
                    @PathVariable("folder") folder : String,
                    @PathVariable("templateName") templateName :String,
                    @RequestParam("doctype") doctype: DocumentType,
                    @RequestBody data: String) : ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> {
        val locale = localeResolver.getLocale(request)
        val printedReport = printerService.printReport(folder, templateName, doctype, data, locale)
        return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(printedReport.mediaType)
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; fileName=" + printedReport.filename)
                .body(InputStreamResource(ByteArrayInputStream(printedReport.content)))
    }

}
```

At the moment this is working fine, but what I don't understand is: do I really have to use the `AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver` class in this way? I read lots of posts that shows how to override default configuration of the `LocalChangeInterceptor` but to me it looks like that class needs a URL parameter that contains the "lang" parameter, and then he resolves using that parameter, but what I want to do it's to simply use the header. Is there a way to define an interceptor that reads only from headers the language and than allows you to access that value, maybe throught the `LocaleContextHolder` class?

All previous posts/questions seems to lack a bit of code, I tried almost all of them by I end up with non working code or exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind... I've simplyfied my controller in this way:

```
@RequestMapping("/rest/report")
@RestController
class PrinterController(private val printerService: PrinterService) {

    @PostMapping("/{folder}/{templateName}", consumes = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE])
    fun printReport(@RequestHeader(name = "accept-language", defaultValue = "en") lang: String,
                    @PathVariable("folder") folder: String,
                    @PathVariable("templateName") templateName: String,
                    @RequestParam("doctype") doctype: DocumentType,
                    @RequestBody data: String): Mono<ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource>> {
            logger.debug{ "Payload to print: $data in language $lang" }
            return printerService.printReport(folder, templateName, doctype, data, lang)
                .map { report -> ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(report.mediaType)
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; fileName=${report.filename}")
                .body(InputStreamResource(ByteArrayInputStream(report.content))) }
    }

}
```